# Set .NET CLR Version to No Managed Code

Tags: iis, wix, asp.net-core

Im trying to build an installer for my asp.net core service, but im having problems setting the `.NET CLR Version` on IIS app pool. Is there any way to set it to `No Managed Code`?

Setting `<iis:WebAppPool ManagedRuntimeVersion="No Managed Code">` results in error `The worker process failed to pre-load .Net Runtime version No Managed Code.`

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Solution is to use "" instead of "No Managed Code" when setting managedRuntimeVersion.

Comment: You cannot select "" in IIS GUI

Comment: this is correct but remember property name is case sensitive: **managedRuntimeVersion**

```Set-ItemProperty -Path IIS:\AppPools\your_apppool_name -Name managedRuntimeVersion -Value ""```

Answer (score 1):

Use the below sample method to create Application pool with No Managed Code

```
public void CreateApplicationPoolDotNetCore(string appPoolName)
{
    using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
    {
         ApplicationPool newPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools.Add(appPoolName);
         newPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = "";
         newPool.Enable32BitAppOnWin64 = true;
         newPool.ManagedPipelineMode = ManagedPipelineMode.Integrated;
         serverManager.CommitChanges();
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The iis:WebAppPool/@ManagedRuntimeVersion attribute's value cannot be an empty string.