# Configure Application Pool .NET CLR Version using C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, iis, iis-manager

When trying to assign a Managed RunTime Version version with this code:

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
    {
       ApplicationPool newAppPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools.Add("HICS");
       newAppPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = "No Managed Code";
    }
```

It sets the version to "No Managed Code", but it's not the right selection. I end up with this:
[image]

If I select the other "No Managed Code", the App Pool works just fine. Why is it creating a duplicate option? How can I select the existing "No Managed Code"? Using C# code of course..

Comment: That solved it... Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try setting it to `""`, like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44161115/2957232).  It should still work, although they are setting this value in a slightly different method.

```
using (ServerManager serverManager = new ServerManager())
{
   ApplicationPool newAppPool = serverManager.ApplicationPools.Add("HICS");
   newAppPool.ManagedRuntimeVersion = "";
}
```